# Want to display time between clicking button and clicking div

Tags: javascript, timer

Hello and thank you for reading this. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am trying to make a function that, when triggered by the push of a button, starts a timer and then displays a div in a random location. When the div is clicked, JavaScript records the time between the press of the button and the click of the div and returns it in a paragraph. I got the square to work but the timer does not work and affects the performance of the rest of my code. Here is what I have so far.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <p id="TotalTime"> </p>
    <button id="funbutton" onclick="SeeWhatHappens(funbutton)">Click here!</button>
    <div id="newdiv" class="a"></div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function SeeWhatHappens(button) {
    var startTime = new Date();
    var divsize = 50;
    var posx = (Math.random() * window.innerWidth - divsize).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * window.innerHeight - divsize).toFixed();
    var div = document.getElementById('newdiv');
    div.style.left = posx + 'px';
    div.style.top = posy + 'px';
    div.style.display = 'block';
    button.style.visibility = "hidden";
    var something = document.getElementById('newdiv');
    something.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    something.onclick = GetTime(startTime) {

}

function GetTime(startTime){
var endTime = new Date();
var timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
var timeDiff /= 1000;
var seconds = Math.round(timeDiff % 60);
timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);
var minutes = Math.round(timeDiff % 60);
timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);
var hours = Math.round(timeDiff % 24);
timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 24);
document.getElementByID('TotalTime') = timeDiff;
}
```

EDIT: Here's my JSFiddle in case it helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/6hnLx6qc/17/

Thank you so much again for any help you can give me!

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/usertiming/?redirect_from_locale=ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version:

```
var button = document.getElementById('funbutton');
button.addEventListener('click', SeeWhatHappens);

function SeeWhatHappens() {
    var startTime = new Date();
    var divsize = 50;
    var posx = (Math.random() * window.innerWidth - divsize).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * window.innerHeight - divsize).toFixed();
    var div = document.getElementById('newdiv');
    div.style.left = posx + 'px';
    div.style.top = posy + 'px';
    div.style.display = 'block';
    button.style.visibility = "hidden";
    var something = document.getElementById('newdiv');
    something.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    something.onclick = function() {GetTime(startTime);};
}

function GetTime(startTime){
var endTime = new Date();
var timeDiff = endTime - startTime;

var timeDiff = timeDiff / 1000;
document.getElementById('TotalTime').innerHTML = timeDiff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6x4ho4ga/1/